# Delete messages from queue

Tags: c, message-queue

I have several processes sending a message to another process (A) through `msgsnd` with the same `mtype`.
The process A recives one of the messages in the queue through `msgrcv` and then should delete all the others messages in the queue with a specific `mtype = contact_id`.
Code of the senders:

```
msg.mtype = (long)contact_id;    
if (msgsnd(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(msg) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The senders send only one message per proccess to A.

Code of process A:

```
       msgrcv(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(msg), contact_id, 0); //first recive
        while ((num_bytes = msgrcv(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(msg), contact_id, 0)) != -1 && errno != ENOMSG) { 
        printf("return value = %d - errno = %d %s\n",num_bytes, errno, strerror(errno));
      //code
        }
```

This is my solution but it does not work. It enters in an loop and doesnt exit from it. Output: `return value = 24 - errno = 0 Success`
How can I edit the while condition?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. “It doesn’t work” is essentially useless information. If it worked, you wouldn’t be asking the question. What is going wrong?  How do you know?  Please provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: It enters in an loop and doesnt exit from it. I insert a printf inside the while

Comment: Edit the information into the question.  You need to capture the return value from `msgrcv()` and print that and `errno` in the loop so you know why it continues to loop.

Comment: This is what is printed inside the while:  return value = 24 - errno = 0 Success

Comment: Does it enter the loop once?  Or many times? Do you need to specify a “return immediately if there is no message waiting” option in the function call?

Comment: It enters many times. Do you mean the flag `IPC_NOWAIT`?

Comment: Say that it enters many times in the question. This information is important. I shouldn’t have to fight to get every drop of relevant information from you.  Yes, it could be IPC_NOWAIT; I don’t have the manual of hand. We need an MCVE with the sender code; maybe it is sending a lot of these messages.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You should capture and report the information from the `msgrcv()` call outside the loop, but that doesn’t explain why the code in the loop continues to succeed.  It’s as though you’re peeking at the queue without removing the message.  Check the manual page carefully.

Comment: The `msgrcv()` outside the loop seems to work correctly and returns no errors. I tried the flag IPC_NOWAIT but nothing change. I'm not using the flag `MSG_COPY` so the message should be removed.

Comment: I don't have a good explanation of what's going on — I said "as if" because that's what seems to be happening.  Without an MCVE that reproduces the problem, there's nothing more I can do to help.  If you decide you will post the MCVE (sender and receiver), then add a comment with the `@Jonathan` notation to summons me back to look again.  As it stands, I've no idea what's going wrong.  It might be a good idea to identify the platform you're working on.  I assume the code compiles without warnings even under excruciatingly fussy options?

Comment: AFAICT, you're probably lying to [`msgrcv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgrcv.html).  The manual includes the information: _The argument msgsz specifies the size in bytes of mtext. The received message shall be truncated to msgsz bytes if it is larger than msgsz and (msgflg & MSG_NOERROR) is non-zero. The truncated part of the message shall be lost and no indication of the truncation shall be given to the calling process._ You pass `sizeof(msg)` but if you look at the manual, it should be `sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long)`.  I'm not sure it matters, but with no MCVE…